# How to create a dynamic specification field based on the category of the product for ecommerce website

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
{_id: "0234weasq43rq",
title: "Tshirt",
descr: "blah blah",
category:'dress',
price: 152,
specifications {
   Type: Cotton,
   Size: L
}
}

{_id: "0234weasq43rq",
title: "Samsung Galaxy Tab",
descr: "blah blah",
category:'electronics',
price: 132,
specifications {
   weight: 135,
   color: "white",
   standard: "GSM",
   wifi: "Yes"
}
}
```

In the above example specification is based on the category. So how can we achieve such a schema in Mongo DB